# resample image during upload in joomla

Tags: image, joomla, image-manipulation, resampling

Unfortunately no exists a component that do it. Only if i insert images in the article. I need to create a php script on joomla that resample images upload from users on frontend during upload process. Someone could tell me how build this script and where i have to insert it?
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by resample image?

Answer (score 0):

Which component you are using for this functionality. Are you using any existing joomla component or you are creating it by your own.

If you are creating your component, add the script which is mentioned in the link below

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/upload-and-resize-image-with-php.html